# How to return complex object as scalar type in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Let's imagine we have GraphQL API that can return an object **Entity** with **Id** and **Name** properties and I requested **Name** only:

```
query {
    entities {
        name
    }
}
```

And it returns

```
{
    "data": {
        "entities": [
        {
            "name": "Name1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Name2"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

But what if I want to have only the name of entities as a scalar type? In other words, I want to have something like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "entities": [
            "Name1",
            "Name2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have such result without changes on the GraphQL API side? Aliases, Fragments, etc. GraphQL has a lot of built-in query capabilities, but none of the known me can return complex objects as scalar type.

Comment: Share the Type definition schema for Entities?

Comment: entities(): [Entity]
Entity:
id: int!
name: String

Comment: You can create an enum type with values Name1, Name2.. but you will need server side changes to let graphql know how to process the enum

Comment: Thanks, but I have few clients with different needs, trying to find way without changes, GraphQL is flex for that, but not in all cases :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're asking for is almost impossible if you don't want to change the type definition for `Entities`.

This:

```js
Entity: id: int! name: String
entities(): [Entity]
```

returns an array of objects with keys `name` and `id`.

To achieve what you're asking you either change `Entity` to be just a string or have your client reduce that object to an array of just `Entity names` when they receive it.

They could do something like this:

```js
const data = {
  entities: [
    {
      name: 'Name1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Name2',
    },
  ],
};

const entityNames = data.entities.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => [...acc, curr.name],
  []
);

console.log(entityNames);
```